# Angularjs $anchorScroll not working in ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My script is based on http://plnkr.co/edit/De6bBrkHpojgAbEvHszu
But all my links with the ID anchors are within the view, and every time their clicked it doesn't take me to the element it just reloads the view.
Any ideas?

**The script I'm using**

```
/*Intercept onpage anchor hash usage: <a href="#/test?scrollTo=foo">Test/Foo</a> */
Site.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
})
```

**One of my links**

```
<a href="#/article/10?scrollTo=test" target="">Test</a>
```

**The element I'm navigating to**

```
<h3 id="test">Test</h3>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information or reproduce your problem in your own plnkr. Otherwise anyone's answer is just going to be a shot in the dark.

Comment: This is the best I could replicate it while keeping it simple: http://plnkr.co/edit/CqqsWqkIgJzq8A1zwFQW

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

It seems that you want to link to specific parts of articles using AngularJS $anchorScroll to do it.

I had troubles to edit any of the Plunkers posted here. It seems they have a cache problem. 
So I created a pen for it: http://cdpn.io/kBqmj

Unfortunately, you can't have multiple HTML files there, so I hard-coded the partial templates, but it should have the same effect with external files.

I separated the code into two controllers to make it easier to debug.

The **home view** has two links that point to different parts of the same article:

```
<ol>
  <li><a href=\"#/article/1?scrollTo=InterestingStuff\" target=''>Article 1: Interesting stuff</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"#/article/1?scrollTo=ImportantStuff\" target=''>Article 1: Don't miss it stuff</a></li>
</ol>
```

The **article view** then basically has some content and two elements with the ids as before:

```
<p>A lot of introduction, followed by something else</p>
<br> 
... 
<br>
<h1 id='InterestingStuff'>Interesting stuff in the middle</h1>
<br> 
... 
<br>
<h1 id='ImportantStuff'>Important stuff at the end</h1>
```

I can't say exactly why it was not working for you, so take a look at my code. I hope it serves at least as a starting point for your on solution.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers (yours and Langdon's) helped me achieve what I needed to. However when I try to send the url with the scroll to, it doesn't automatically scroll to the area, you have to click the link again. Is there a hack for this?

Comment: @Stephen: If you tested using the code pen you will not be able to paste the url in the browser and expect it to work. Codepen uses an iframe for the actual code, so changing the browser url does not reflect the url that the angular code sees. If you change directly the iframe src using the web developer tools of your browser, you can see that it goes to the desired place. I would suggest you try it on your local machine.

Comment: I did this on my local machine, if I navigate to the url with the scrollTo on the end it navigates me to the top of the page, but when I click on the link within the page it navigates me to the propor location. Could this  be because it is loading the view after the page document is loaded?

Comment: @Stephen: It works for me on both Chrome and Firefox. I think I can't help you anymore without knowing exactly how and what you are running.

Comment: @Stephen I am hitting this EXACT same issue, where I am generating an error and THEN trying to scroll, but `$autoScroll` (with `$location.hash()`) seems to reload the controller completely (wiping my errors from the View)...I too had to click twice to get the error to stick...did you end up finding a remedy to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The plnkr you provided didn't actually make use of $anchorScroll, but I'm assuming that was removed when you tried to recreate what you were working with.  If you put back the `Site.run` code you referenced that called $anchorScroll, it of course still doesn't work.

The problem has to do with your anchor's href, which was mangled a bit.  This is what you want:

```
<a href='#?scrollTo=VerifyingDeviceStatus' target=''>...</a>
```

Things flow a bit differently when you're using the hash to navigate.  As in the working example you provided, hash is used at the beginning of the url, and the scrollTo "querystring" parameter does not need an extra #, as it's implied by $anchorScroll.

Fixed plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1pHKjnAgo6hwjQvardy?p=preview

~

What's the deal with the following statement?

```
var result = data[0].content.replace(/href="#/g, 'href="#/article/' + slug + '?scrollTo=');
```

Perhaps this is the cause of your problem.  It doesn't do anything in the plnkr, because you're using single quotes instead of double, but if you change the HTML to use double, it reloads the page as you described:

http://plnkr.co/edit/sdxjlRWkiLr53L6MELTZ?p=preview

It takes a perfectly working url like: "#/article/23?scrollTo=VerifyingDeviceStatus" and turns it into this "#/article/undefined?scrollTo=/article/23?scrollTo=VerifyingDeviceStatus", which obviously won't work.

What exactly are you trying to do with this RouteController?

Comment: Hmm, I think that is what I currently have - I suppose I made a bad attempt on the plnkr. This is what my links on my pages look like right now: `<a href="#/article/36?scrollTo=requesting-proposal">Requesting Proposal</a>` and when I click them, the url looks like this: `http://url.com/beta#/article/36?scrollTo=requesting-proposal#requesting-proposal` and the view reloads when they are clicked as well.

Comment: The statement you questioned replaces all of the hrefs with the proper format, as there are loads of articles in the database and I figured this would be the best way to test it. I tried hardcoding the html in the database to: `<a href="#/article/23?scrollTo=VerifyingDeviceStatus" target="">Verifying: Device Status</a>` and it still does the same thing.

Comment: You can still do the replace statement, you just need to be mindful of what the final href is.  When you copy link address, what does the link look like?  Or you can inspect the element and check the href attribute.

Comment: This is what the href attr looks like in the dom: `<a href="#/article/23?scrollTo=VerifyingDeviceStatus" target="">Verifying: Device Status</a>`

Comment: That's what it should be.  Without seeing your actual code, I don't think I can help you anymore.  The only way I can get my latest working plnkr to just reload the page using a link like that is if I take out the `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess'...` bit.